# about kendo ui upload in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I want to use kendo ui q2 2012 in mvc3. i use the way of this link:

http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction

but in my razor view , instead of showing this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
        )
```

it shows this:

```
@Kendo.Mvc.UI.Upload
```

and i can't use it. help plz. thanks...

another question is that can i use Telerik.Web.UI in mvc3? 
when i add it to my project same kendo that i said above, it doesn't show htmlHelper type.

Comment: You need to use the code described in the documentation and not @Kendo.Mvc.UI.Upload.

Comment: @AtanasKorchev what code do u see that i can't see it? i don't know why i can't use htmlhelper of kendo, but i can use jquery form of it :(

Comment: Check my response and the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [upload overview help topic](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/upload/overview). It shows how to configure and use a Kendo Upload in ASP.NET MVC. Here is the relevant code:

View (Razor):

---

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("attachments")
        .Async(async => async
            .Save("Save", "Home")
        )
)
```

Controller:

---

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
{
    // The Name of the Upload component is "attachments"
    foreach (var file in attachments)
    {
        // Some browsers send file names with full path. We only care about the file name.
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var destinationPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

        file.SaveAs(destinationPath);
    }

    // Return an empty string to signify success
    return Content("");
}
```

Comment: it doesn't show "@(Html.Kendo().Upload()" for me. when I write @Html. intellisence doesn't show "Kendo" . therefor i can't use it. it shows same "@Kendo.Mvc.UI" . i don't know that version 2012 q2 has Html helper or not.

Comment: Check the troubleshooting help article: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/troubleshooting#visual-studio-intellisense-does-not-show-the-kendo-htmlhelper-extension-method

Comment: thaks, i checked it again , i had added namespace before and rebiult my solution, but html.Kendo doesn't show yet. :(

Comment: oh! Thanks, I had mistake! I added namespace and rebuilt solution, but i forgot to close view and reopen it! sorry Atanas and thanks alot for helping..